# Are there any pros and cons in using these two different styles in Client/Server communication?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

Okay I have two different styles in communicating with my Server-Side PHP and i want to know if there are any downsides to both based on your expert opinions.

First off is a complete string sent from my **Client-side HTML** to my Server-side PHP

```
function myCall(){
var name1 = "myName";
var name2 = "myOtherName";
var myString = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND name='"+ name1 +"' AND secondName='"+name2+"'";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        recievedData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        recievedData.forEach(function(item){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += recievedData.name;
        });
    }

};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "myphp.php?q="+myString,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And is then received by the **Server-side PHP**

```
$q = $_REQUEST['q'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = $q;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));
$outp = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $outp[] = $row;
}


echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

**And then there is this other method. --------------------------------------**

```
function myCall(){
var name1 = "myName";
var name2 = "myOtherName";

var myString = name1 + " " + name2;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        recievedData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        recievedData.forEach(function(item){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += recievedData.name;
        });
    }

};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "myphp.php?q="+myString,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And is received by this PHP but it uses `explode()` to turn it into an array that the php can understand.

```
$q = $_REQUEST['q'];
$exp = explode(" ", $q);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND name='"+ exp[0] +"' AND secondName='"+ exp[1] +"'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));
$outp = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $outp[] = $row;
}


echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

Both give back the same results but are different methods entirely so... based on your expert opinions, what can go wrong with these two different styles?

Comment: IMO, you should not write a SQL request in your HTML/JS code, for it will appear in the page's source code. Hence the second solution seems better.

Comment: You have left yourself wide open to sql injection attacks there

Answer (score 1):

The first method has a serious security flaw.

1. It exposes the structure of your database.
2. It excepts a SQL statement directly from a client-side string

This makes you database vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: but then again the first method can be broadened if you are only limited to  one php and by a cleaver usage of a combination of `explode` and `strpos` you can completely secure the data received by the php

Comment: @Arkonsol no.. you can never trust anything coming from the client. Never assume you are smarter than the bad guy at the other end. Do all you can to secure your database. That includes NEVER publically exposing anything to do with the structure of your database. All I need to do is view the HTML in the source to get that info. Then it would be trivial to use inbuilt browser tools to change the SQL to drop tables, truncate data etc.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 is like house with door frame, but without the door. Both method are allowing people to go inside your house, but option 1 are alowing anyone goes inside, with or without you knowing. When method 2 will check the person (parameter) before you allow them go in.

If you dont mind anyone that know those link mess around with your database, sure you can use method 1.

You should know that is called [SQL injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)